# Error with Stack Function in R

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and have been trying to find a solution to an error I am getting when I attempt to stack data. I'm trying to run a one-way anova with three variables. When I attempt to stack the data with `stack("Combined_Groups")` I get the following error:

> Error in rep.int(names(x), lengths(x)) : 
>        unimplemented type 'NULL' in 'rep3'

I've copied my R syntax below in case that is helpful.

```
rpeople1 <- c(.74, .70,  .36, .29, .33, .51, .34)
rmixed1  <- c(.58, .40,  .02, .12, .32, .06, .26)
rthing1  <- c(.25, .05, -.06, .07, .10, .13, .19)

summary(rpeople1)
#   Min.  1st Qu. Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 0.2900  0.3350  0.3600  0.4671  0.6050  0.7400 

Combined_Groups <- data.frame(cbind("rpeople1, rmixed1, rthing1"))
Combined_Groups
# cbind..rpeople1..rmixed1..rthing1..
# 1          rpeople1, rmixed1, rthing1
summary(Combined_Groups)
#         cbind..rpeople1..rmixed1..rthing1..
# rpeople1, rmixed1, rthing1:1               

Stacked_Groups <-stack("Combined_Groups")
# Error in rep.int(names(x), lengths(x)) : 
#  unimplemented type 'NULL' in 'rep3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the inverted commas " " around your created objects, R interprets them as a character vector.
The function `stack` expects a proper data.frame and yours is only one observation of one column.
Removing the " " from your code in the construction of the `data.frame` and the `stack` call yields the solution:

```
rpeople1 <- c(.74,.70,.36,.29,.33,.51,.34)
rmixed1 <- c(.58,.40,.02,.12,.32,.06,.26)
rthing1 <- c(.25,.05,-.06,.07,.10,.13,.19)

Combined_Groups <- data.frame(cbind(rpeople1, rmixed1, rthing1))
Combined_Groups
Stacked_Groups <- stack(Combined_Groups)
Stacked_Groups
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to successfully fun the ANOVA. I will keep that in mind for future codes as well!

Answer (score 0):

Function `stack()` is used by multiple packages. Try to specify the package that you want to use with stack, e.g. `raster::stack (packagename::functionname)`.